# AS2 - How to split a string of text to make a function and a variable

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Ok so I have a debug system I am working on for a flash game, and I have a Switch(case) block in there here is what I have so far.

```
switch (fstring){

case "player.getname":
var pname = _global.heroVars.playerName;
target.feedback.text +=  (ct + pname + "\r\n");
target.inputt.text = "";
break;

case "player.getlevel":
var plevel = _global.heroVars.userLevel;
target.feedback.text += (ct + plevel + "\r\n");
target.inputt.text = "";
break;

default:
target.feedback.text += (ct + "\"" + inp + "\"" + " is not a valid function\r\n");
target.inputt.text = "";
}
```

My question is how can I make one so it's a "Set" function. For instance
"player.setlevel NUMBERHERE" or "player.setname STRINGHERE" etc. And take the 2nd part of a the string and use said number or string to set a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it.

With the example of this string "**_player.addlevels 2**" as the var **inputFunc**

```
var mystring:String = inputFunc; // sets it to a new var to not mess up the original
var sepString:Array = mystring.split(" "); // splits "_player.addlevels" and "2"
var func:String = sepString[0]; // sets this string to "_player.addlevels"
var inputVar:String = sepString[1]; // sets this string to "2" which can be anything and cast into another var type

switch(func){ // takes our variable with the string "_player.addlevels"
    case "_player.addlevels":
        _global.playerLevel += int(inputVar); //since they are using this function we know that they are using and integer and thus cast the string to an int
    break;
}
```

Don't know how I didn't see it before but I ended up solving my own problem. So there's the answer in case anyone is curious